# How to addslahes to multidimentional array values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

`var_dump($array);` gives:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Mark O'Donel
                    [id] => 35802624
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Da's Messager
                    [id] => 522505962
                )
        )
)
```

Any idea how to add slashes to array the values?
Trying the following but it's not working:

```
foreach($array as $list){
    foreach($list as $elt){
       $name = $elt['name'];
       $id = $elt['id'];

       echo 'before: '. $name .'<br><br>'; // Assuming $name= "Mark O'Donel"
       $list[$id] = addslashes($name);
       echo 'after: '. $elt['name'] .'<br><br>'; //suppose to give Mark O\'Donel
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want addslashes?

Comment: The idea is to have a json encoded value. The apostrophe sign seems as to create problem with the json parsed value in the jquery

Comment: `json_encode` takes care of all the escaping you need …

Comment: @Lomse - re creating json.... you don't need to be doing that manually. Are you aware of the `json_encode()` function?

Comment: `array_walk_recursive($array, 'addslashes');`

Comment: @knittl Of course but it seems not to escape values of an array wich is already in another array

Comment: @SDC Of course but it seems not to escape values of an array wich is already in another array

Comment: @Lomse - `json_encode()` **does** escape the json string properly, even for nested arrays. You shouldn't need anything more than `print json_encode($nestedArray);` to produce valid JSON output. If you're doing that and not getting valid JSON output, then that would warrant further investigation, but the answer would not involve needing to manually escape anything.

Comment: @SDC The var_dump of the json_encoded version of the array gives me: {"data":[{"name":"Katelyn Gault","id":"2624"},{"name":"Zak Le Messager","id":"45489"}, {"name":"Mark O'Daniels","id":"19073"}}. Mark O'Daniels seems not to be escapped.Thanks again for your answer

Comment: What SDC said … `json_encode` handles nested arrays just as well as regular ones.

Comment: In the example you've given, the single quote in `"Mark O'Daniels"` does not need to be escaped, because the string is double-quoted. It should not give you any problem in Javascript to have it the way you've shown it. If you are having problems with it, then maybe there's something in your javascript code that is incorrect. If you had a string with a double-quote in it, that would need to be escaped, and yes, `json_encode()` would escape it, but the single quote doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The changed value has to be assigned to the array variable:

```
foreach($array as $list){
    foreach($list as $index=>$elt){
       $name = $elt['name'];
       $id = $elt['id'];

       echo 'before: '. $name .'<br><br>'; // Assuming $name= "Mark O'Donel"
       $list[$index]['name'] = addslashes($name);
       echo 'after: '. $elt['name'] .'<br><br>'; //suppose to give Mark O\'Donel
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have changed and why?

Comment: The value after adding slashes is not being updated in the array variable.